Why only one front chainring for MTB?
Why only one front chainring for MTB ?
Is it a short-term trend or it is a must for MTB (XC) ?
Is it better than 3x8 or 3x7 (3 front and 7 rear cogs) ?
UPDATE:
Later I found a very similar question:
Are single chainring mountain bikes usual?


The first modern 1x (with narrow-wide chainrings and clutch derailleurs) was released 12 years ago, and it's currently almost impossible to find mid-range and high-end MTBs with double (or triple) chainrings - bike manufacturers don't even care to manufacture frames with support for front derailleurs. The very conservative Shimano recently upgraded their entry level ranges (CUES and ESSA), to have single chainrings options for these price points. Shimano has announced that the last high-end 3x (XT Trekking) will be replaced by the 2x CUES U8000. So it's not really a "short term trend".

"Better" is a subjective term. The 1x vs 2x vs 3x debate has been rehashed many a time. A 2x system's front derailleur is easier to adjust than a 3x. A 1x doesn't have one, so there is even less to worry about.
You cannot cross-chain with a 1x, and it frees up space on your handlebars, which, on a mountain bike, would come in handy for a dropper post lever.
The downsides are obvious: If you want to suddenly change into a very low gear, you can drop the chain onto a smaller front chainring, if you have one. What's more, you only get as many different gear ratios as your cassette has gears with a 1x system. This means that if you want a wide range of gears, the steps between them will necessarily be big. Adding a cog in the front allows retaining that range while using a smaller cassette (so the jumps between gears are smaller). You can try playing around with gear ratio setups using Sheldon's gear calculator to see what ratios you would be missing out on: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gear-calc.html
I personally don't think this is a short term trend. I can't even remember the last time I saw a bicycle with a triple front chainring in a store.
What you might consider when comparing a 7 and 8 speed system is that within one manufacturer's groupset generation, it will be the more expensive groupset that has more speeds. This doesn't necessarily tell you that 12 rear cogs are better than 11, which are better than 10, and so on, but it does tell you that the quality of the groupset and the ease of shifting will be better if you choose the system with more cogs (usually it will also weigh less).

As the question specifically asks about MTB, one of the biggest advantages is missing:
Better chain retention.

Your point about bigger steps between gears may be true for 3x10 or 2x11 but at the same gear range the steps of 3x7 are bigger than 1x12.
I would say 1x12 is better then 3x7 or 3x8 in every aspect, except cost and maybe availability of spares in some places

@airace3 I like my 3×9 hardtail for the combination of range and spacing, for XC/exploring and trail centres, which I generally ride to on road.  It was better on both counts than the 1×11 I hired recently (though that was a better bike in other ways).  So I'm prepared to spend a fair bit of effort keeping it going rather than replace the bike. Similarly for road/gravel I have 3×9 and 2×11 bikes; I prefer the gears of the former, but everything else on the latter.

@ChrisH when comparing 3x9 vs 2x11, extreme ratios are as important as the cog combination. I have at home 3x9 (commuter, utility oriented), 2x10 (light MTB) and 2x11 (modern gravel). The modern gravel lacks range to my opinion, and the narrower intermediate steps are more a hassle. The best compromise is the 2x10, that has the same range as the 3x9 (46/30 front, 11/42 rear), and a wide range cassette allows to mitigate the main drawback of narrow range cassettes: the requirement to change chainrings frequently, but I'll soon modify the gravel to have same ratios.

@Rеnаud  That 2×11 is my gravel bike and similarly limited.  I've fitted (but not yet tested except on my street) an 11-36 cassette (RD says max 34) on my gravel wheelset. I may look at a bigger big ring, though I'd be exceeding the total capacity of the RD then - but I think I'd get away with that too as I realised my chain is too long anyway (I should have known better than to copy someone else's length).

@ChrisH I'm in a similar situation with the gravel (2 wheelsets, one for road 11/36, one for gravel 11/34). My idea is first to fit an 11/42 cassette (with a RD-RX812, modified with a RD-M8000-SGS cage). Next step is to increase chainring size (when replacing worn components), the 11/42 rear would allow to even have a 50/34 front while still having a very decent low range when used with the gravel wheelset.

@ChrisH to be fair, 1x11 is pretty niche. 1x12 with 10-51/52t cassettes were standard on MTBs for the last 4-5 years and i was comparing it to the 3x7/3x8 in the question.
The difference 1x12 vs 3x7 is much bigger than 1x11 vs 3x9 ;)

@airace3 true, but 3×7 is either old or BSO-level basic. Even the old pseudo-MTB I keep at work is 3×8, like my old hybrid which was did pretty well. But 1×11 (Marin San Quentin 2) and  1×10 (Canondale Habit) are still common from mainstream brands; you can even find 1×9 (Marin San Quentin 1)!

Ok, true. There are some, but i wouldn't call it common. 1x11 or less is reserved to the cheapest entry level MTBs. But most manufacturers i know sell their entry level builds wit 1x12.

@airace3 I'm under the impression that the cheapest entry level from mainstream brands having 2x Acera/Alivio (the cheapest Trek MTB has a Tourney drivetrain), but Acera/Alivio starts to be phased out and be replaced by CUES now, so the number of 1x9-1x11 will increase. Shimano also released a "modern" 1x8 (ESSA, narrow-wide/clutch). Some may argue that the bikes equipped with ESSA/CUES are not real MTBs, but that another topic ;)
